# Is there any way to deploy list views for custom settings through Metadata API?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, customsetting, list-view

Currently trying to deploy a list view created for custom settings through the 'Manage' button through the Metadata API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customSettingsType>List</customSettingsType>
    <description>Test custom setting</description>
    <enableFeeds>false</enableFeeds>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Test_Field__c</fullName>
        <description>Test field for custom settings example.</description>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Test Field</label>
        <length>100</length>
        <required>true</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <label>Test Custom Settings</label>
    <listViews>
        <fullName>Test_List_View</fullName>
        <columns>NAME</columns>
        <columns>Test_Field__c</columns>
        <columns>LASTMODIFIEDDATE</columns>
        <filterScope>Everything</filterScope>
        <label>Test list view</label>
    </listViews>
    <visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

Error is as follows:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  objects/Test_Custom_Settings__c.object -- Error: Cannot specify: listViews for CustomSettings
```

Looks like it's not possible to deploy these list views but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation. Not surprising, as 'Manage' also deals with custom setting data which can't be deployed between environments.

Any suggestions other than a post-deployment manual step to create this view?

Thanks!

Edit: Looks like there's an idea for this to be implemented:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KBa8AAG

Comment: It's a bit of a side step, but you could try using Custom Metadata Types rather than Custom Settings. I'm not actually sure if this will address the list view deployment problem, but Custom Metadata Types are a newer replacement for Custom Settings and would likely give you more options.